# How to reliably compare Symbols when using reflection or macros?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

How can I reliably compare two `Symbol`s for equality in scala macro or when using reflection? Is it guaranteed that when two `Symbol` objects represent the same symbol (the same class, the same local value or variable, etc.) they will be equal in terms of `==` operator?

What do I need this for? I have a `Tree` in a macro that represents some expression that may reference some local value. I want to transform this tree and replace all references to this local value with references to some other value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `==` (or `eq`, the reference equality comparison, which does the same in this case) is the way to go to compare symbols.